# Displaying a datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

> I've a problem wiz binding a datalist from 2 tables .... I used this code 
>        DataSet ds = DataManager.ExecuteDataSet("select_unionmembers_full_info");

```
    ds.Tables[0].TableName = "unionmembers";
    ds.Tables[1].TableName = "user_sign_up";

    ds.Relations.Add(new DataRelation("stunion", ds.Tables["unionmembers"].Columns["stuid"],

    ds.Tables["user_sign_up"].Columns["stu_id"], false));

    alreadyexistdl.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

    alreadyexistdl.DataBind();
}
```

> and here is the join query I used (select_unionmembers_full_info)
>    select * , username,id from unionmembers , user_sign_up where stuid=stu_id
>   and this error appears to me !
>   **Cannot find table 1.**
>        Line 14: 
>   Line 15:         ds.Tables[0].TableName = "unionmembers";
>   Line 16:         **ds.Tables[1].TableName = "user_sign_up";**
>   Line 17: 
>   Line 18:         ds.Relations.Add(new DataRelation("stunion", ds.Tables["unionmembers"].Columns["stuid"]
>
> **here is the Stack Trace:**
>
> ```
>  [IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find table 1.]
> ```
>
> System.Data.DataTableCollection.get_Item(Int32 index) +79
>      stunion_unionadmin.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in g:\New graduation project_2\Do7h Book 1\stunion\unionadmin.aspx.cs:16
>      System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
>      System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +670

Comment: seems your dataset has only a single table

Comment: but how ! ... the query has to return results from 2 tables !

Comment: Post the entire code so we can see where the 2 tables come from.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get two table results, you need to pass two db commands.  Like this for example:

```
CommandString = "SELECT foo0 FROM foo0; SELECT foo1 FROM foo1;";
sda = new SqlDataAdapter(CommandString, conn);
ds = new DataSet();
sda.Fill(ds);
dt = ds.Tables[0];
dt1 = ds.Tables[1];
```